# Plot 3D to classify the data

Tags: plot

I have a set of data and I want to plot them in 3D (so I could decide how many groups or class I have)
I need the simplest and easiest way to do it.
These are my data:

```
 x ,      y ,      z                   
0.91,    0.14,   -0.57     
0.74,    0.97,   -0.49     
0.34,    0.96,   -0.37     
0.42,    0.98,   -0.29     
0.71,    0.87,   -0.27     
0.72,    0.85,   -0.24     
0.63,    0.86,   -0.14     
0.36,    0.77,   -0.01
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and easiest is to get someone else to do it for you.  I used this code to configure [Orson Charts for HTML5](http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/web/) to create the scatter plot in a web page:

```
      <p><canvas id="scatter_chart_canvas" width="640" height="400"></canvas></p>

      <script type="application/javascript">
        function initScatterChart() {
          var dataset = [{ series: 'Data', values: [ [0.91, 0.14, -0.57], [0.74, 0.97, -0.49], [0.34, 0.96, -0.37], [0.42, 0.98, -0.29], [0.71, 0.87, -0.27], [0.72, 0.85, -0.24], [0.63, 0.86, -0.14], [0.36, 0.77, -0.01] ] }];
          var chartConfig={
            title: 'Stack Overflow 22678789',
            plot: {
              xAxis: { label: 'X', gridlinesVisible: true },
              yAxis: { label: 'Y', gridlinesVisible: true },
              zAxis: { label: 'Z', gridlinesVisible: true },
              dimensions:[5, 4, 5]
            },
            style: 'Orson 1'
          };
          configureOrsonXYZChart3D('#scatter_chart_canvas', chartConfig, dataset);
        }
      </script>
```

Here is a link to the live chart:

http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/web/so22678789.html